# Adjust drive latency/lag on Server 2008 server with an array?

Tags: windows-server-2008, latency

Got a 2008 server in production , which currently has "one" disc. (Actually a SAS array, presented as a single disc to the OS.)

This "disc" is partitioned into a few sections, with some free space left over.

Someone has the app on the server running off of the C: partition. A bit of lag was sensed and we presumed that the OS tasks might be slightly affecting the app performance.

So, we took some free space and created a logical volume there. Put the app onto the logical volume, by itself. Now the app lags slightly more.

Anything we can do to address this slight lag for some performance, disc-wise? (besides putting in another separate array and moving the app there?)

Comment: Please include the output from the following command: wmic partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index

Comment: You're omitting the most important details in your question. What type of server/array/RAID controller are you using? Make and model, please.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are correct that the operating system "tasks" are causing latency, then moving your app to a new partition on the same logical RAID volume will not improve anything. It's exactly the same set of disks so your two partitions will share the available performance bandwidth. If disks are really the problem then you will need to reconfigure your RAID array to dedicate some disks to your application's partition.

However, the disk performance needs of a Windows 2008 server are almost negligible. Instead of guessing at what the performance problems are you should instead be performing monitoring and analysis to find the true cause of the problem.